# Why wp_nav_menu does not retrieve menu in correct order?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I am trying to pull menu on my header.php using following code:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
    'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
) );
```

And in my admin login Appearance > Menu, main-menu is in following order:

```
Home
About
Tours
Pages
   Contact Us
   Help Desk
   Gallery
Destinations
Blog
Booking
```

But in header the order is jumbled and even doesn't show the submenu also.
Order on header

```
About
Pages
Tours
Booking
Home
Blog
Destinations
```

Help me out! I even tried using order_by/sort_column, they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Below code is what you looking for.
Add your `Menu Name` Instead of  '`Main menu`'

```
<?php
    $main_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Main menu');
    $customize_arr = array();
    if(!empty($main_menu)){
        foreach($main_menu as $mm){
            $mm = (array) $mm;
            if($mm['menu_item_parent'] == 0){
                foreach($main_menu as $sm){
                    $sm = (array) $sm;
                    if($mm['ID'] == $sm['menu_item_parent']){
                        (array)$mm['submenu'][] = $sm;
                    }
                }
                $customize_array[] = $mm;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

In **$customize_array** you will get all the `menus` with `sub-menu` you just have to do `foreach` loop with your html code.

100% Working code..I hope the Code Will help You!

Answer (score 0):

If you developed the theme from scratch then add the following as an index of your array

```
'orderby' => 'menu_order'
```

Would be somthing like below

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
    'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
) );
```

If you are working on an already developed them then the issue is with `'theme_location'` index of the array, so change it to `'theme_location' => 'primary'` it will be something like below:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
) );
```

Comment: I tried both the way and it isn't working either way.